# Sending emails as company domain from SendGrid

Tags: c#, azure, sendgrid

I own a domain, example.com. I'd like to send out emails from my webapp where it displays it's from *info@example.com*, or *support@example.com*.

I've used SendGrid a lot in the past from within my websites, but I've always simply been able to fill out where an email is from by editing the `From` property of the `SendGridMessage` class, and it just showed up that way on clients.

Is there an official way/API from sendgrid to utilize a domain that I own? What's to stop me or someone else from typing any domain they want using the sendgrid API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of setting up DNS records for your domain that allow your emails to be authenticated, as well as verifying your ownership of the domains, is known at SendGrid as [whitelabeling](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/Whitelabel/index.html). After this process, SPF and DKIM records will then be available for receiving servers to check.

[SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) ensure the originating IP is allowed to send email on behalf of the domain in question, and to essentially verify that the contents of the email have not been tampered with respectively.

The thing that will stop others from sending from your domain is called [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC). Domains owned by yahoo, aol, and very soon google all implement strict policies; emails claiming to be from these domains but that are not will never be delivered. Many other domains will soon be following this trend and implementing DMARC.

Comment: Thank you very much. So when I type in a very popular, known domain (like `whitehouse.gov`), and send that out internally to my colleagues, it works because our mail server isn't performing DMARC?

Comment: it works because the domain you've used (whitehouse.gov) doesn't implement DMARC, or the DMARC record for that domains specifies a p=none policy so that failing SPF and DKIM don't matter

Answer (score 1):

The code sample from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/ shows how to do this:

```
// Create the email object first, then add the properties.
var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();

// Add the message properties.
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("john@example.com");

// Add multiple addresses to the To field.
List<String> recipients = new List<String>
{
    @"Jeff Smith <jeff@example.com>",
    @"Anna Lidman <anna@example.com>",
    @"Peter Saddow <peter@example.com>"
};

myMessage.AddTo(recipients);

myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";

//Add the HTML and Text bodies
myMessage.Html = "<p>Hello World!</p>";
myMessage.Text = "Hello World plain text!";
```

Comment: I may be missing what you're referring to, but I tried to be specific with one of my questions that stated, `What's to stop me or someone else from typing any domain they want using the sendgrid API?`. I could simply type `obama@whitehouse.gov` in the `From`. I'm looking for something a little more *proper* (?) than that.

Comment: I'm sorry; I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: All good! I may not have been very clear. Thank you for taking the time to help out though. I appreciate it!